problema con vs code y javascript
Por necio, estuve instalando extensiones en VSCode y al correr un proyecto elaborado en HTML, CSS y JS, todo parece bien hasta que ejecuto eventos de javascript, como por ejemplo: al presionar el botón calcular, debe primero verificar que estén los input con datos, si no aparecerá un párrafo: "este campo es obligatorio",  colocando la propiedad en JS de ...style.display='inline' ya que en CSS lo coloqué como display:'none'.
Pero en el navegador, al presionar se muestra el párrafo por un instante y vuelve a desaparecer y es así para todas las acciones de JS. Ya resetee el JS, lo desinstalé y nada.
Agradezco de su colaboración, ya que esto me tiene estresado, ya que no se a que se debe esto si anteriormente todo estaba bien.
<body>
    <form class="container">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        <div class="input__flex">
            <div class="caja">
                <h2 class="title">First Name<span>*</span></h2>
                <input type="text" class="input__dato">
                <p class="required">This field is required</p>
            </div>
            <div class="caja">
                <h2 class="title">Last Name<span>*</span></h2>
                <input type="text" class="input__dato">
                <p class="required">This field is required</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="input__submit" onclick="btnSubmit()">
    </form>
</body>


Pero y que tiene que ver vs code con lo que te esta pasando???

Cuidado con las extensiones de VSCode, muchas funcionan mal y algunas contienen código malicioso, intenta tener las mínimas posibles. Por otro lado quizás solo sea un problema con tu código, añade un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable de lo que estas haciendo y quizás podamos ayudarte. Puedes hacer esto editando tu pregunta, o eliminando esta y creando una nueva.

ok, tomé una porcion del codigo y desabilite el css para solo correr con html y js y aun así sigue igual

este es el script ejemplo
let req = document.querySelectorAll('.required');
function btnSubmit(){
req[0].style.display = 'inline';
}

La verdad que contestar de esa forma a alguien que intenta ayudarte no va a sacar lo mejor de nosotros..

El evento submit tiene el comportamiento por defecto de recargar la página, debés evitar esto con el método preventDefault(), esto es algo bastante común cuando recién empezás con HTML + JS.
Para eso, pasá el evento como argumento a la llamada de función:
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="input__submit" onclick="btnSubmit(event)"> 
<!-- para las llamadas a funciones en HTML, el argumento debe llamarse 'event' y ningún otro nombre -->

Y en la definición de la función, definís el parámetro que será el evento, y llamas a preventDefault dentro:
function btnSubmit(e){ 
  e.preventDefault()
  req[0].style.display = 'inline'; 
}

Pero lo normal, y es una mejor práctica, es no llamar a funciones dentro de HTML, sino seleccionar el formulario en el script (agregándole un id) y mediante un eventListener, manejar el evento allí, algo como esto:


let req = document.querySelectorAll('.required'); 

document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  req[0].style.display = 'inline';
})
  <form id="myform" class="container">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    <div class="input__flex">
      <div class="caja">
        <h2 class="title">First Name<span>*</span></h2>
        <input type="text" class="input__dato">
        <p class="required">This field is required</p>
      </div>
      <div class="caja">
        <h2 class="title">Last Name<span>*</span></h2>
        <input type="text" class="input__dato">
        <p class="required">This field is required</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="input__submit"> 
  </form>




muchas gracias, la verdad venia haciendo los ejercicios así y no tenia problemas, pero desde que me puse de necio con las extensiones todo se fue al caño, de todo lo malo siempre hay algo bueno, aprendi algo de todo esto una manera mas estetica de hacer esta parte
